# In Schrödinger's cat, what is the role of the box?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedingers-cat

At university, I asked the question in regards to the classical thought experiment Schrödinger's cat, what is the role of the box?  Unfortunately, I didn't get a satisfactory answer. If fact, most were in some ways condescending in that it was considered to be a trivial question. However, I do not see this as trivial as if it was, then there would not be the need for a box in the first place.

What role does the box play? How does it inform/shape our understanding of quantum mechanics? What is the equivalence to the box in the quantum world? Does it have an equivalence in the classical world?

Comment: What's wrong with this question? In my view, it's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the box is to prevent you making an observation (in rather old-fashioned QM speak) of the cat.  Since doing that causes the wavefunction to collapse (again, in perhaps old-fashioned terminology) it is rather important that you can't do so, or you just have a cat.

Comment: @Countto10: I'm not sure.  When I learnt QM it was all Copenhagen interpretation & I haven't really kept up with how people think of it now.  I was hoping some new-fashioned person would be able to tell me :-)

Comment: So if the box is to prevent one from making an observation, then the box cannot be made of transparent plastics...? If so, why so?

Comment: A box made of transparent plastic is not isolating the cat from the rest of the world, because light can pass. So it's not a _Schrödinger's box_.

Comment: @Countto10: When I learned it (which was 1980s) all the people who worried about interpretation were basically hippies: my conclusion was that there was a significant possibility that worrying about interpretation would turn you into a hippy & that 'shut up & calculate' was the only punk rock approach to QM.  (Writing this as an ex-hippy you understand.)

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the fact that the the Schrödinger's cat experiment is just metaphorical and it wouldn't work in the real world: the cat is just not isolated enough from the rest of the world to have a quantum behaviour.
So the Box must indeed be interpreted as a way to isolate the cat enough to have quantum coherence, even if such a box could not exist.

Comment: Yes, I have had this reply at univeristy. But the idea of it being metaphorical is a cop-out. The thought experiment is set up as a means to explain (in some form) aspects of QM. As a poor analogy, we don't say fuselage on an aircraft is metaphorical just because the engines provide foward thrust and the wings lift - an aircraft is a complete system. The Schrödinger's cat experiment is a system - so what roles does each component play? Surely someone has addressed this before? All we hear about is whether the cat is dead or alive..that's the easy part.

Comment: When I say that this thought experiment is metaphorical I mean that is too much idealized: there will never be a way to perform it because a box that will isolate the cat enough from the rest of the world cannot exist. So the box is an ideal separation between the rest of the world and the quantum cat and they cannot communicate in any way: i.e. no measurement can be done without opening it.